# Is Apache Ignite Capture Data Change (CDC) only supported on some platforms?

Tags: ignite

On Ubuntu 22.04/Ext4 I setup 2 Apache Ignite 2.15 clusters ("A" and "B") with working [CDC](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/change-data-capture): `ignite-cdc.sh` is running - I put keys/values to cluster A and they are propagated to B. Great!

I tried to do the same on Windows 10/NTFS and it's not quite working. At `ignite-cdc` startup key/values are sent but I am not receiving `CdcEvent`s, and further key/value puts are not propagated.

What am I doing wrong and how to debug this?

Details:

On two Ubuntu 22.04 PC's with Ext4 filesystem I setup 2 Apache Ignite 2.15 clusters ("A" and "B") and, on one of them, I setup the simplest working CDC (cluster "A"'s CDC becomes Thin Client of cluster "B"):
`defaultDataRegionConfiguration` with `<property name="CdcEnabled" value="true"/>` + `<property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>` and a `<bean class="org.apache.ignite.cdc.CdcConfiguration">`  consuming events using `IgniteToIgniteClientCdcStreamer` pointing to `Addresses` of cluster "B". It works - as long as `ignite-cdc.sh` is running, I put keys/values to cluster A and they are propagated to B.

On Windows 10 (NTFS) I start `.bat` equivalent to `ignite-cdc.sh`; and it **does** copy key/value pairs *on startup* from "A" to "B" but not when key/value pairs are inserted to "A" *after* `ignite-cdc` was started.  I do see `.wal` file timestamps change so I guess persistence is working but I am not receiving `CdcEvent`s.